# How update the value of input and send into Request Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, forms

i need change some values of my form with JS.
i yeah, i can see the changes in my form, but when i send the form in my request i cannot see the values that i modify with javascript.

this is code js where i make the updates

```
               var estructure = $('#SimpleJSTree').jstree(true).get_node(parents[i]).original;
                switch (estructure.est) {
                    case 'fondo':
                        //document.getElementById("found").value = estructure.est;
                        $('#found').val(estructure.est);
                        break;
                    case 'serie':
                        //document.getElementById("serie").value = estructure.est;
                        $('#serie').val(estructure.est);
                        break;
                    case 'subserie':
                        //document.getElementById("subserie").value = estructure.est;
                        $('#subserie').val(estructure.est);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

and this is tags that i want changes, obviously all this are in tag form

```
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <span>Fondo</span>
                            <input id="found" value=""type="text" placeholder="Found" name="found" disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <span>Seccion</span>
                            <input id="section" type="text" placeholder="Section" name="section" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <span>Serie</span>
                            <input id="serie" type="text" placeholder="Serie" name="serie" disabled value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <span>Sub Serie</span>
                            <input id="subserie" type="text" placeholder="Sub-Serie" name="subserie" disabled value="">
                        </div>
```

and this is the request and how you can see in the request i dont have the value of the input that i change

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyc9m.png)

Comment: Dont use disabled, if you use disabled then data wont get passed .

Comment: @Senthil yeah, that's true. thank you so much bro i confuse the tag i want said readonly

Comment: if you find it useful, pls upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs have disabled attribute which means they are not send after form submition just remove that and you should be able to see your inputs on backend

Comment: yeah, that's true. thank you so much bro i confuse the tag i want said readonly